# Database Sorting depending on Integer?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

in my database having some row's , in every row having three column's(id, name, moves, time). i want to sort the rows depending on the moves this is the integer value.

i tried like this but unlucky.

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
         KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES);
}
```

used like this

```
private void getallrows()  {
    // get all the contacts..
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.fetchAllNotes();       
    if (c.moveToFirst())   {        
       do {
          Sorting(c);
       } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}
```

moves i have like 15, 45, 21, 11, 10,75,33
i want like this  10,11,15,21,33,45,75

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
         KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " ASC");
```

or

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
         KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " DESC");
```

**EDIT - 1:**

If you want to display name,you can use like this,

```
private void getall()
{ 
        db.open(); 
        Cursor c = db.fetchAllNotes();
        int i=1; 
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {               
            do
            {
                DisplayContact(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME))); 
                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        } 
        db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: i change as u said , and call this function here private void getall()  {  db.open();  db.fetchAllNotes(); Cursor c = db.getAllContacts(); if (c.moveToFirst()) { do { dislayContact(c);   } while (c.moveToNext()); before display it's not display in order.
  }
  db.close();
 }

Comment: sorting not in ascending order. 10,10,12,4,6,64

Comment: Firstly,please write code in proper format. And here you might have problem in showing values because your fetchAllNotes() returns Cursor object which is not catched here in your code.

Comment: I think,you are not clear which method you want to use. Whatever it is,you just need to change you query's last parameter as i mentioned in my answer to get it sorted.

Comment: i am using like this private void getall()  { db.open(); Cursor c = db.SortAllRows(); int i=1; if (c.moveToFirst())  {     
do { DisplayContact(c,i++); } while (c.moveToNext()); }  db.close();
 }

Comment: public Cursor SortAllRows() { return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " ASC"); }

Comment: i think it's sorting first digit.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont u make query in such a way which return the sorted data itself ???
Try out This query :

SELECT *
FROM DATABASE_TABLE
ORDER BY KEY_MOVES ASC

or

db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
         KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " ASC");

Hope u get it...

Comment: i am new to android i did't get u please explain it, how to crate.

Comment: Translation: Instead of trying to sort in Java, try leveraging SQLite and retrieve the data already sorted on the column you want. Look at the "order by" part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

Comment: instead of fetching all the records from database , u fetch the recods in such a way which gives sorted recods itself, the query i have written gives the sorted data.

Comment: is this the format return db.query(SELECT * FROM DATABASE_TABLE ORDER BY KEY_MOVES ASC);

Comment: Yes what @Richa has written is a formatted query and solution to your problem.

Comment: use this ...db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, 
         KEY_MOVES,KEY_TIME}, null, null, null, null, KEY_MOVES + " ASC");

Comment: it's sorting but not in correct order : it gives 10,10,12,4,4,6,6,6,64.

Comment: i think it's sorting first digit.